# I try to login but it does not run the whole query

Tags: android, android-volley

When I put something wrong, I receive everything in onResponse but it does not go for the function resultado() and when I put all the data well, it goes to the function resultaod() but only until the time to assign the values ​​to usuario and from the toast it is not executed.

Login Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RelativeLayout parentLayout;
private EditText txtUsuario, txtContraseña;
private TextView txtVersion;
private CheckBox chxRecordar;
private Button btnEntrar;
private SharedPreferences myPreferences;
private Usuario usuario;
private String codes, status, token;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    iniciarComponentes();

    btnEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            verificarInicio();
        }
    });
}

private void iniciarComponentes() {
    parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    txtUsuario = findViewById(R.id.txt_usuario);
    txtContraseña = findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    chxRecordar = findViewById(R.id.chx_recordar);
    btnEntrar = findViewById(R.id.btn_entrar);
    txtVersion = findViewById(R.id.txt_version);
    txtVersion.setText("Version " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
    myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

private void verificarInicio() {
    String url = Common.BASE_URL + "usuario";
    if (validarSesion()) {
        Log.d("verificarInicio: ", url);
        final String usuario = txtUsuario.getText().toString();
        final String contraseña = txtContraseña.getText().toString();
        final android.app.AlertDialog dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).setMessage("Cargando...").setCancelable(false).build();
        dialog.show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    codes = jsonObject.getString("code");
                    status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    token = jsonObject.getString("token");
                    resultado(codes, status, jsonObject, token);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Snackbar.make(parentLayout, error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                HashMap<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("dni", usuario);
                parametros.put("password", contraseña);
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<String> request) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void resultado(String codes, String status, JSONObject jsonObject, String token) throws JSONException {
    if (codes.equals("100")) {
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        JSONObject dato = array.getJSONObject(0);
        usuario = new Usuario(dato.getString("NombreCompleto"),
                dato.getString("estado"),
                dato.getString("foto"),
                dato.getString("nombre_Aso"),
                dato.getString("nombre_Red"),
                dato.getString("sexo_Pro"),
                dato.getInt("campana"));
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Common.USUARIO_DNI = txtUsuario.getText().toString();
        guardarUsuario(token);
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Common.USUARIO, usuario);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else if (codes.equals("200")) {
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, status, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (codes.equals("203")) {
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, status, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


private boolean validarSesion() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtUsuario.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txtContraseña.getText())) {
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Ingrese su usuario y contraseña", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void guardarUsuario(String token) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = myPreferences.edit();
    if (chxRecordar.isChecked()) {
        if (!myPreferences.contains(Common.USUARIO)) {
            myEditor.putString(Common.USUARIO, txtUsuario.getText().toString());
            myEditor.putString(Common.CONTRASEÑA, txtContraseña.getText().toString());
            myEditor.putBoolean(Common.CHECK_ESTADO, chxRecordar.isChecked());
            myEditor.putString(Common.TOKEN, token);
            myEditor.apply();
            if (Common.USUARIO_DNI.isEmpty()) {
                Common.USUARIO_DNI = myPreferences.getString(Common.USUARIO, "");
            }
        }
    } else {
        myEditor.clear();
        myEditor.commit();

    }
}
```

}

The whole code is not executed, only a part, I do not know why, I would be grateful if you helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that recibe in a catch, the problem is when get the string for the jsonObject

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                codes = jsonObject.getString("code");
                status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                token = jsonObject.getString("token");
                resultado(codes, status, jsonObject, token);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```